# Excel: How to find last "valid" value in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook of the following style:

```
| A    | B    | C    |
| 1    | y    |      |
| 2    | y    |      |
| 3    | n    |      |
| 4    | y    |      |
| 5    | n    |      |
| 6    | n    |      |
| 7    | y    |      |
```

In column C I want to have the *last* value from column A *above* the current row which has "y" in column B.

So, the expected output would be:

```
| A    | B    | C    |
| 1    | y    | ---  |
| 2    | y    | 1    |
| 3    | n    | 2    |
| 4    | y    | 2    |
| 5    | n    | 4    |
| 6    | n    | 4    |
| 7    | y    | 4    |
```

NB: I actually want to do this is Google Sheets, but I guess an ordinary Excel function would suffice.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can column A have any values in it, or are they always just the row numbers, always increasing by 1 etc? Are you always selecting the MAX, or is it just the previous value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula must check the "y" in the row previous, so in C2, you need to reference the string in B1, and either use the number in A1, or the previously selected value in column C.

So the formula is:

```
=if(B1="y",A1,C1)
```

Here's a screenshot of what it would look like:
[image]

---

Based on comment by OP, here is another screenshot showing exactly the output as requested in the question above:

[image]

Comment: Richard, I am sorry. Your answer is perfectly correct and does exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PhilippJardas No problem, always best to double check. I redid the work just to make sure, and posted your exact example (which I should have done in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

Put the following formula into cell `C2`, its an array formula so dont include the curly braces but press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` to confirm the formula (instead of just `ENTER`)

`{=MAX(($B$1:$B1="y")*$A$1:$A1)}`

You can drag that formula down. I haven't tested this on Google Docs, but it works with excel.

Answer (score 0):

Please try, in C2 and copied down:

```
=IF(B1="y",MAX(A$1:A1),C1)
```